# Multiple HTTP requests using sockets in java

Tags: java, networking

How could i send multiple http requests from my java program using sockets. actually i have tried as:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class htmlPageFetch{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter dOut = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            dOut.println("GET /mytesting/justCheck.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost\r\n\r\n");
            boolean more_data = true;
            String str;
            int i = 0;
            while(more_data){
                str = dIn.readLine();
                if(str==null){
                    //Now server has stopped sending data               //So now write again the inputs
                    dOut.println("GET /mytesting/justCheck1.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost\r\n\r\n");                          


                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(str);
            }   
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
}
```

But when I send the request again it was not processed?
Thank in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't catch an exception and do nothing with it.  In your exception, at least print the stacktrace (e.printStackTrace()) to see if there's an error.

Comment: Do you have to do this with sockets ? HTTP is abstracted out in several libraries that would clean this up some.

Comment: Another hint: do not generate HTTP packets or any other protocol packets inline. There are LOADS of libraries for that. For example Apache HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html)

Comment: Hey thanks to all you but can't i do with sockets??

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead. It abstracts a lot of HTTP details, including connection pipelining.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear that why you are trying to send request using socket. But you might want to use apache HttpClient to sending the request. Sample can be found here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html